# Significato di "guerra lirica"

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Ferito a morte*, di Raffaele La Capria, ho letto (grassetto mio, ma il corsivo appare nel libro):

> Cavalieri, avvocati, commendatori, adorano Scarfoglio, al massimo sfogliano *Il Popolo dai Cinque Pasti*, o *Folli Vindici e Pirati: le Arringhe Celebri*. Facondi e iracondi, già arringati dal Duce, preferiscono ancora e sempre i gigioni e la genìa dei geni. Il Lussurioso Immaginifico li fe’ sognare d’Oltremare, crispini e libici inneggiarono alla **guerra *lirica***, e poi fascisti a quella lampo.

Potreste spiegare il significato dell'espressione "guerra *lirica*" che appare in questo passaggio? Ricercando alla voce "lirico" di parecchi dizionari, non l'ho trovata.

Ho visto, però, che appare nel [titolo di un libro](https://books.google.es/books?id=CyYTAY9exa4C&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_book_other_versions_r&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false). Fa riferimento alla guerra di Libia degli anni 1911-12? Ha a che vedere, come si menziona nella coperta del libro, con qualche dibattito tra letterati in quel periodo?

Comment: Direi qualche cosa di più che un semplice dibattito tra letterati, vedi per esempio https://www.giorgiopozzieditore.it/collane/la-politica-dei-letterati/30-antonio-schiavulli-la-guerra-lirica-il-dibattito-dei-letterati-italiani-sull-impresa-di-libia-1911-1912.html

Comment: Non so a cosa ti riferisci, @linuxfan, perché non ho idea di cosa sia "guerra lirica": è questa la ragione per cui ho posto la domanda.

Comment: La guerra è quella coloniale in Libia. Guerra lirica nel senso che diede luogo ad accesi dibattiti tra poeti e scrittori del tempo tra cui D’Annunzio e Marinetti. Poeti e scrittori combattono “a suon di liriche”.

Comment: @charo, hai provato a leggere il breve testo che ho riportato a esempio (mezza paginetta)? Spiega velocemente che cosa è stata la "guerra lirica" e perché non fu, secondo me, un semplice dibattito fra letterati.

Comment: Sì, l'avevo letto, @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica.

Comment: @Hachi: Quindi, "guerra lirica" farebbe riferimento a questo accesso dibattito (o cosa veramente fosse) tra scrittoti a proposito della guerra coloniale in Libia degli anni 1911-12?

Comment: Si, il tema del colonialismo era un tema molto controverso. E gli intellettuali del tempo presero posizioni diverse e contrastanti. Una “guerra “ tra opposte fazioni  di sostenitori  e contrari al colonialismo. Trattandosi di letterari la “guerra” tra loro  fu definita “lirica”.